# Find number of white/black pixels in binary image

Tags: image, matlab

I have an binary word image with grid and i want to find the foreground pixels (number of black and white in each segments) in each segments

Comment: How to find segment ??

Comment: That is a different question

Comment: That is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512094/i-have-a-binary-word-image-b-i-want-to-divide-binary-word-image-b-into-c-x-r-se) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your black and white image is `bw`

```
 sum(bw==0) // number of black pixels
 sum(bw==1) // number of white pixels
```

For each grid find the range in both directions, then apply the same idea.

For example, from `x1` to `x2` and `y1` to `y2` is one grid:

```
  sum(bw(x1:x2, y1:y2) == 0) // will give you the black pixels you want
```

Comment: But I don't know the values of x and y

Comment: @raghu the dimensions of segments are known, right? If each segment is a matrix, (:) will give you all pixels in the matrix as Ander Biguri said

Answer (score 1):

So I just wanted to get the total number of black pixels for an image and I didn't want to segment it. Didn't feel like having to learn how to segment a matrix.

Easy fix to get the sum of the black pixels:

```
sum(sum(bw == 0))
```

Conversely to get the white pixels

```
sum(sum(bw == 1))
```

The operation function `sum(bw == 0)` just gets everything to a `[1xn]` matrix, so you will need to perform sum and you will get the whole image matrix summed.

Thought that `cumsum` would do the trick, but `sum(sum())` is just better for this case. Tells you how little I know about coding. Have fun with this info, note that I'm just using this to determine the area coverage of a binarized image, but for anything else particularly useful.

Comment: Actually u can get the number of white pixel. image total pixels  (eg720x480) - #of black pixel... since this is binarized... just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That is easy with logical indexing.

For each segment, do:

```
n_white=sum(segment(:)==1);
n_black=sum(segment(:)==0);
```

Comment: Sir, please give me some programs